# How can a new object of Activity for each notification?

Tags: java, android

I have code for creating notification:

```
    NotificationManager notifyMngr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification=new Notification(mId, "New alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent alert = new Intent(this, AlertInfoActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alert, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, data.get("name"), data.get("post_date"), contentIntent);
    notifyMngr.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
```

I need to create a few notifications, and each notification must execute a new object of  AlertInfoActivity by click. But this code executes 1 object of Activity always. How can I do my task?

Comment: you want to run multiple activities when a user clicks on a single notification?

Comment: no. I execute a few notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a notification for each activity you want to launch. Like this:

```
NotificationManager notifyMngr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//First Notification
Notification notification=new Notification(mId, "New alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent alert = new Intent(this, AlertInfoActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alert, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, data.get("name"), data.get("post_date"), contentIntent);
notifyMngr.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

//Second Notification
Notification notification2 = new Notification(mId, "Second Alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent alert2 = new Intent(this, DifferntAcitivty.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notification2, 0);

notification2.setLatestEventInfo(this, data.get("name"), data.get("post_date"), contentIntent2);
notifyMngr.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification2);

//Third Notification
Notification notification3=new Notification(mId, "Third Alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent alert3 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alert3, 0);

notification3.setLatestEventInfo(this, data.get("name"), data.get("post_date"), contentIntent3);
notifyMngr.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification3);

//And so on and so forth.
```